# Problems Passing WPF form Data to Invoke-Webrequest command as variables

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

Ive been using some great examples from foxdeploy to try and create a gui for a bunch of invoke-webrequest for different scenerios.  The imput will always need to be generated by the user and launch against a cloud provider to create an object

https://foxdeploy.com/2015/04/16/part-ii-deploying-powershell-guis-in-minutes-using-visual-studio/

the issue is no matter what I do, I cannot seem to pass the imput and button click into the invoke-webrequest. command always seems to fail.  Im attempting something like the following:

```
$WPFCreate_User.Add_Click({

    $Form.Add_Loaded({$WPFName_Entry.Text = $NewUser})    

    Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{"X-RRR-Key"="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"} -Method Put -body '{"USER":'"$NewUser"'}' https://api.blue.net/v1/Users/$NewUser
})
```

Ive been at this for 2 days, and have tried numerous ways to grab the imput and imput into the Put Body field and just cant figure it out.  Running the invoke-webrequest by itself is fine with no issues.  running from script works as well.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue that I see if that you have some fundamental issues with your string that you are using for the body:

```
'{"USER":'"$NewUser"'}'
```

First, you have unescaped single quotes within your string, and you are trying to perform string expansion within single quotes (which doesn't work); either that or you are trying to perform string concatenation without a connector. What you can try is this:

```
$WPFCreate_User.Add_Click({

    $Form.Add_Loaded({$WPFName_Entry.Text = $NewUser})    
    $body = '{"User":"{1}"}' -f $NewUser
    Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{"X-RRR-Key"="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"} -Method Put -body $body https://api.blue.net/v1/Users/$NewUser
})
```

See if that works better for you.